# Не понимаю как исправить ошибку CS0200

Tags: c#, type-error, tuple

Не понимаю как исправить ошибку. У меня есть данный кусок кода:

```
int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
List<Tuple<int, int>> v = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
List<Tuple<int, int>> rl = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    rl[rl.Count - 1].Item2 = v[i].Item2; //< CS0200
```

Как можно исправить тут ошибку? Я понимаю, что у меня разрешено только для чтения, но не знаю как разрешить запись. В коде нужно добавить второй элемент из списка v в конец списка rl.

PS: пробовал еще так

```
rl.Last(new Tuple<int, int>(rl.Count - 1, 0)) = v[i].Item2;
```

но тут появляется новая ошибка CS1503

Comment: 1. У вас в примере дублированная строка.
2. Кидайте полный кусок кода, что за rl? Что такое N?

Comment: Все читающие должны ошибки по номерам помнить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще тут двухслойная ошибка в одной строке.

1. Изменение картежа из массива по индексу. - Вы используете Tuple, но свойства Tuple всегда доступны только для чтения, чтобы изменить одно из свойств Tuple, нужно полностью заменить Tuple на только что созданный Tuple с нужными вами изменениями.\ - Используйте ValueTuple.
2. Изменение TupleValue в массиве. - Нельзя изменять свойства структур в массиве.

Так из вашего кода нужно сделать:

```
int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
List<(int, int)> v = new List<(int, int)>();
List<(int, int)> rl = new List<(int, int)>();
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    rl[rl.Count - 1] = (rl[rl.Count - 1].Item1, v[i].Item2);
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш пример. 
Программа показывает новую ошибку CS1612 у строки:

rl[rl.Count - 1].n2= v[i].n2;

Comment: @NightXFox, изменил код, проверяйте

Comment: Большое спасибо!